# How to grant permissions across a whole Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I  have problem

```
kubectl get all
```

shows

```
Error from server (Forbidden): replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "replicationcontrollers" in API group "" at the cluster scope
Error from server (Forbidden): daemonsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "daemonsets" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope
Error from server (Forbidden): deployments.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "deployments" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope
Error from server (Forbidden): replicasets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "replicasets" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope
Error from server (Forbidden): statefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "statefulsets" in API group "apps" at the cluster scope
Error from server (Forbidden): cronjobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "cronjobs" in API group "batch" at the cluster scope
Error from server (Forbidden): jobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:svcaccount" cannot list resource "jobs" in API group "batch" at the cluster scope
```

I applied role and rolebindings but still get the same. I am looking at example from offical docs

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to read secrets in any namespace.
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-secrets-global
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: manager # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

How should I change in case of svcaccount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `clusterrole` will give you access to the whole cluster :

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- nonResourceURLs:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

You can then reference it from a `clusterrolebinding` like this :

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

And in case you want to attach it to a service account rather than the group `manager` :

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-service-account
  namespace: my-namespace
```